# Acquiring an Android WakeLock in NativeScript App

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I've almost finished a NativeScript app that integrates timers as part of the UI. (I repeat, a NativeScript app. NativeScript is kind of like React Native. It's written in JavaScript, not Java.) The user will create a timer that runs for up to ~100 minutes but could run for as little as 1 second, with the expectation that an alarm is guaranteed to go off at the end of this process, whether or not they've been using their phone. When I run this application on my phone, after the phone's screen has been locked for a while (I'm not sure exactly how long it takes, but probably 10-30 minutes), alarms don't go off and the app relaunches to the home page. I ideally want the state of the app to be completely preserved and the processing that goes on in my Angular component to continue while the screen is off. Yes, I know this is a drain on battery life.

Right now, the code I'm using to enforce a partial wake lock in Android looks something like this:

```
acquireWakeLock() {
    //enforce a new partial wake lock
    const PowerManager = android.os.PowerManager;
    let powerManager = <PowerManager>application.android.context.getSystemService(android.content.Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    this.wakelock = <PowerManager.WakeLock>powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "RoutineTimer");
    this.wakelock.acquire();
    console.log("Acquired new wake lock");
}
```

(Forgive the verbose references, but I'm putting them here to distinguish between "android" and "application.android".)

This doesn't have the desired effect at all. It's being called from an Angular component but is housed in an Angular service.

Does anyone know what's up with this or have other recommendations? I'd prefer not to use a full (screen) wake lock, though I know there's a plugin for that. I'd also prefer not to send in any kind of broadcast from a server for financial reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured out how to get a wake lock going, the caveat being it's not tremendously useful right now (and would be quite wasteful, so I'm not using the approach anymore).

If you want to use an Android wake lock, you have to put this code in an *Android* service, whereas mine was simply in an Angular service (there seems to be no issue having a class that serves as both). I thought it could be done from anywhere in the codebase, hence the problem.

The last answer [here](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/how-to-start-android-background-service-in-typescript/1989/4) gives a solid description of how to start an Android service with TypeScript (which I couldn't find in the actual docs). The above code can pretty much be dropped right in there.

I think a better approach might be to use an AlarmManager, but I still don't have a clue how to keep a somewhat cross platform approach and execute my NativeScript JS code from within the Java code. Ideally there would be a NativeScript plugin that handles scheduling tasks at arbitrary times.

Anyway, my solution for now is to use the nativescript-local-notifications plugin and schedule a notification at a specific time. Unfortunately executing code at the time the notification comes in isn't supported yet (but is a feature request).

Comment: Any progress on this? I want to poll from an IP every 10 mins and FCM seems like a little too much with its requirements (domain name, SSL).

Comment: @inf3rno not really. I haven't looked into it for a really long time, though, so there may be a better fix by now. The nativescript-task-dispatcher plugin looks like it might be useful for scheduled tasks